# client waiting on server promise to resolve

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, fetch-api

I have a scenario where I'm performing a fetch request to an express server. The express server is then performing a fetch request to a rails api service. So I have the client side waiting on a promise to resolve, and that promise will resolve once the server-side promise resolves after communicating with the rails api.

and on the express side, I'm only calling `res.json()` once the promise on the server resolves.

here's what the server request looks like:

```
apiRouter.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const partnerId = 'id';
  const apikey = 'key';
  const apikeyIdentifier = 'id';
  const cerebroUrl = `http://${apikeyIdentifier}:${apikey}@localhost:3000/v1/${partnerId}/login`;
  const data = {
    //data
  };

  httpRequest(cerebroUrl, httpMethods.post, data).then(response => {
    res.json(response);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response.status);
    res.json(error.response);
  });
});
```

and the client request:

```
const url = '/api/login';
const data = { username, password };
return httpRequest(url, httpMethods.post, data).then(response => {
  console.log('success', response);
  return response;
}).catch(error => {
  console.error('error', error);
});
```

and I have a helper method that checks the status before resolving:

```
export const checkStatus = response => {
  console.log(response.status);
  console.log(response);
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) return response;
  let error = new Error(response.statusText);
  error.response = response;
  throw error;
};
```

the weird thing is, in the checkStatus method the console is logging 200 for a response status, but in the the client `request.then` the response has a 422.

I believe the initial client request is first resolving as a 200, but then when the server promise resolves and I get a 422, the client side is already past that stage. Or something...

Is there a way to handle the promises in a way that's more predictable?

here's what the fetch request function looks like:

```
export const httpRequest = (url, method, data) => {
  return fetch(url, {
    method,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  })
  .then(checkStatus)
  .then(parseJSON)
  .then(response => {
    return response;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging I found out that I have to set the status code manually on the server-side promise `.catch`

```
apiRouter.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const partnerId = 'id';
  const apikey = 'key';
  const apikeyIdentifier = 'id';
  const cerebroUrl = `http://${apikeyIdentifier}:${apikey}@localhost:3000/v1/${partnerId}/login`;
  const data = {
    //data
  };

  httpRequest(cerebroUrl, httpMethods.post, data).then(response => {
    res.json(response);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response.status);
    res.status(error.response.status); // <-- HERE ---
    res.json(error.response);
  });
});
```

otherwise it was returning a 200, which is strange because the error.response is an object whose status is 422, and the `checkStatus` function checks that. Maybe I'm misunderstanding what is actually sent back when performing a `res.json()`

it doesn't make sense to me though because before setting the status manually, I had the following catch:

```
 .catch(error => {
      res.json(error.response);
    });
```

and 2 console.logs:

```
export const checkStatus = response => {
  console.log(response.status);
  console.log(response);
```

and these were returning:

> 200
>
> {... status:200, statusText: 'OK' ...}

and all I changed so far is this:

```
.catch(error => {
  res.status(error.response.status);
  res.json(error.response);
});
```

and now it logs:

> 422
>
> {... status:422, statusText: 'My custom status text' ...}

I don't understand why changing only the res.status also updates the response object itself...